# How to git clone https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git

Tags: git, linux-kernel, clone

```
    git clone https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git
```

But the error occur as follow:

```
    Cloning into 'linux'...
    error: Couldn't resolve host 'git.kernel.org' while accessing https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/info/refs
    fatal: HTTP request failed
```

What should I configure git ?

Comment: No Need to configure git.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to execute the same git command without any error. Seems to by issue in connectivity or DNS. See if you can use Google DNS 8.8.8.8 or 8.8.4.4

[image]